# Codeigniter после переноса на другой домен, не работают роуты

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Выдает ошибку: The requested URL `some/url`.. was not found on this server ( 404 )

В базе все заменил.
Файл .htaccess взял сначала тот-же, заменил домен - не работает
Потом взял дефолтный .htaccess codeigniter все равно не хочет,

Может есть какие-то идеи куда двигаться?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кое-что забыл дописать в файл конфигов apache:

`<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>`